# When is/isn't equality preserved under taking the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I have a poor memory, but I am quite certain that last year we made quite a fuzz in one of my PDE classes about equality being preserved under the limit - i.e. that this was something which was not immediate. Unfortunately, due to said memory defect I cannot recall the details. However the idea is something like this:

Given $f_n=g_n \forall n$, $f_n \to f$ & $g_n \to g$. In which situation, relevant to analysis, is $f\neq g$?

Reason for asking is that when working in $R^n$ this is apparently immediate, by uniqueness of the limit. And so I looked like quite a knobhead when asking the question in class (where we were dealing with $R^n$) and if possible I would like to avoid such a situation in the future.

Comment: It's never true !

Comment: In real analysis, we have uniqueness of limits. However, in more general topological spaces that are not Hausdorff, it is possible to have more than one limit. So, it's possible for $f_n \to f$ and $f_n \to g$ without being able to conclude $f = g$. But, in any case, $f$ and $g$ are limits of both $f_n$ and $g_n$, as they are the same sequence.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was after. I realise it's not clear from the way I phrased the "idea". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n=g_n$ then the symbols $f_n$ and $g_n$ are notations/labels for the same mathematical item, so it cannot happen that in that case $f_n\to f$ and not $g_n\to f$.

Moreover if it concerns limits here then the demand that $f_n\to f$ *determines* $f$ so then it is not possible that $f_n\to f$, $g_n\to g$ and $f\neq g$.

Answer (score 0):

To have $$\lim f_n=\lim g_n$$ , it is sufficient to have

$$f_n=g_n\text{ for } n\ge N$$

And $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n\in \Bbb R$.

not for all $n$.

observe that

$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;\; f_n=\sin^2(n)=1-\cos^2(n)=g_n$$

but
neither $\lim f_n$, nor $\lim g_n$ exists.